# Auto complete in text field in odoo12

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-12

- Auto complete in text field in odoo12 using `name_search`

  i added a field `code_artcile` in product template and i am trying to
  use it on account invoice to select a product.

  ```
  class AccountInvoiceInherited2(models.Model):

     _inherit = 'account.invoice.line'
     code_article_id = fields.Char(string='code article',store=True,related='product_id.code_article')
  ```

  trying to use it on account invoice to select a product

Comment: Still you didn't explain what is your actual issue or need.

Comment: @Ajmal i added a field code_artcile in product template and i am trying to use it on account invoice to select a product.

Comment: Please check to see if the field is inherited to product.product, if not, make sure it inherits to product.product.  Product.product or Product Variants are the references for essentially all product fields in Odoo, such as sale orders, invoices, purchase orders, etc.

Comment: @CristinMeravi it inherits product.template

Comment: @khaledtouati Did you restart your server and update or install your custom module?  Also make sure you have any necessary dependencies in your manifest.